# In mongodb java driver how to sort by using two fields

Tags: mongodb-java

using mongo java driver I am able to sort like so:

```
.sort(new BasicDBObject("firstColumn",1));
```

How do I sort by two fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
.sort(new BasicDBObject("firstColumn", 1).append("SecondColumn", 1));
```

Comment: How can i iterate this sorting condition based on nth conditions

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui Not sure I follow you. Can you give me an example ? If you can please create a new question with the details and I will happy to answer there.

Comment: pls see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624067/mongodb-how-to-sort-and-search-multiple-field-in-a-collection-using-java

Comment: please check above mentioned question and let me know in case of any confusion in the same post